# Incorporating ngcordova plugin results in errors

Tags: ionic-framework

In order to incorporate the Toastr ngCordova plugin.. I followed the following steps

1. bower install ngCordova
2. include ngCordova in my app

   angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
3. Install plugin

   cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin.git
4. Use the plugin

   app.controller('myController', function($cordovaToast) {

   });

This seems pretty straight forward. However I encounter the following errors:

```
ionic.bundle.js:21157 TypeError: Cannot read property 'toast' of undefined
    at Object.show (http://localhost:8100/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js:9:20474)
```

I am running the app in chrome browser.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Test this feature using your device device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ngCordova** plugins won't work in the browser.

From [documentation](http://ngcordova.com/docs/common-issues/):

> **Only develop on your phone**
>
> Cordova plugins do not work while developing in your browser, because each plugin accesses a specific API (such as camera, microphone, accelerometer) which is not available in your browser. Additionally, some plugins don't work in the emulator, such as the Camera plugin, so development on your physical device is required.

In this case be sure that your application works on your device.